# Strange java error in Android Studio with two modules

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints, android-studio-2.2

I'm currently developing, in Android Studio, a Google Endpoints application in java. I therefore have two different modules in the project:

1. A "backend" module where is all my code for the Google Endpoints backend (including java beans which define my model and data store data model and auto-generated Endpoints)
2. An "app" module where there is the code for the corresponding Android App which will talk to the back-end.

I get the following error in the "backend" error when I call isEmpty() on a string: "Call requires API level 9 (current min is 1): java.lang.String#isEmpty".

Note that:

- It seems that this error only appeared when I started to add code to the Android "app" Module. Before that, during the last year, I didn't have any problem. OR it could be that it started when I upgraded to Android Studio 2.2
- I can build and deploy the "backend" module to App Engine without any problem despite the error and the class with the error works correctly.
- In the build.gradle fiel of the "app" module I have:

  ```
  defaultConfig {
   applicationId "com.xxxx.yyy"
   minSdkVersion 14
   targetSdkVersion 23
   versionCode 1
   versionName "1.0"
  }
  ```
- In the Android Manifest of the Android app I didn't have any uses-sdk declaration. Adding one with e.g. android:minSdkVersion="14" didn't change anything.
- I can build and deploy the "backend" module to App Engine without any problem despite the error and the class with the error works correctly.
- I get the error in any class of the "backend" module: a simple bean, a generated Endpoint that I modify, or a "custom made" Servlet.

Comment: Use [`TextUtils.isEmpty`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: @JPVentura Thanks for your answer. The thing is that this error occurs in the "backend" module which normally shall be nearly fully independent from the Android part.

Comment: Hi have you been able to resolve?

Comment: @Enoobong: I'll have to check. I had to switch of project and I don't remember if I solved it. I will come back to you in the next few days.